# Dynamic In App Purchases - is it possible?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, in-app-purchase

i just finished setting up In app billing in my ionic/cordova app. now i'm wondering, can i make the item selected for purchase dynamic?

**right now im using this**

```
              $scope.buy = function() {
                if((window.device && device.platform == "Android") && typeof inappbilling !== "undefined") {
                    inappbilling.buy(function(data) {
                        alert("ITEM PURCHASED");
                    }, function(errorBuy) {
                        alert("ERROR BUYING -> " + errorBuy);
                    }, 
                    "ad_free");
                }
               }
              }
```

**but is it possible to use something like this for my in app purchases?**

```
             $scope.buy = function() {
                var thisPurchase = "world" + index + 1;
                if((window.device && device.platform == "Android") && typeof inappbilling !== "undefined") {
                    inappbilling.buy(function(data) {
                        alert("ITEM PURCHASED");
                    }, function(errorBuy) {
                        alert("ERROR BUYING -> " + errorBuy);
                    }, 
                    thisPurchase);
                }
               }
              }
```

Regards, one happy developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

As long as you can control and change the required parameters to pass in the methods you can dynamically select which sku to pass and hence get dynamic in-app purchase.

Comment: I already +1'd you but here is personal thx, thanks for the quick response and straight to the point answer! really helped me! (need to build alpha everytime i want to test so saves me a lot of time)

Comment: Glad to be of help ... :)